# Getting an arrow to point at a specific (x, y) point

Tags: javascript, css

Hello I'm attempting to to have two arrows pointing at a specific (x, y) point or in the general area of a button.

I would like two arrows coming from each of the boxs pointing in the general area of the button. I can do this fine with regular css on certain screens but when the screen is resized or smaller then the arrows no longer point to the button. I'm just trying to figure out a good way to handle this.

So really what I'm asking is what would be good way to go about having two arrows appended after 2 divs pointing at the same point. (The Red Square)

[image]

JSFIDDLE: 
https://jsfiddle.net/kxw7jquu/

HTML

```
<div class='app-info-panel'>
  <div class='app-info-panel-header'>
    <h1>Data-sources</h1>
  </div>

  <div class='data-source-panel-wrapper' id='source_report'>
    <h1>Report_File</h1>
    <div class='data-source-panel'>
      <div class='data-source-info'>
        <h3>Report Id</h3>
        <h2>1</h2>
      </div>
      <div class='data-source-info'>
        <h3>Report Name</h3>
        <h2>Medicine-stock</h2>
      </div>
      <div class='data-source-info'>
        <h3>Date</h3>
        <h2>02/16/18</h2>
      </div>
      <div class='data-source-info'>
        <h3>Reporter</h3>
        <h2>John Smith</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='source-arrow' style="transform: rotate(50deg); top: -10px">
      &#10141;
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class='data-source-panel-wrapper' id='source_order'>
    <h1>Order_movement</h1>
    <div class='data-source-panel'>
      <div class='data-source-info'>
        <h2>ID: 1</h2>
      </div>
      <div class='data-source-info'>
        <h2>Medicine-stock</h2>
      </div>
      <div class='data-source-info'>
        <h2>02/16/18</h2>
      </div>
      <div class='data-source-info'>
        <h2>John Smith</h2>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='source-arrow' style="transform: rotate(130deg); bottom: -40px; left: 60px">
      &#10141;
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <button class='data-source-button'>Order Filling</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.app-info-panel {
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 30rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;

  h1 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: 500;
  }
}

.data-source-panel-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  user-select: none;

  .source-arrow {
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(50% - 50px);
    bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 12.5rem;

    color: #D6D7D8;
    transform-origin: left;
    z-index: 1;
  }

  h1 {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    color: #0481E2;
    text-align: center;
  }
}

.data-source-panel {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.37);
  z-index: 2;

  .data-source-info {
    h3 {
      color: #0481E2;
      margin-top: 0;
      margin-bottom: 3px;
      font-size: .8rem;
      line-height: normal;
    }

    h2 {
      margin: 0;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: 400;
      line-height: normal;
    }
  }
}

#source_report {
  .data-source-panel {
    .data-source-info {
      margin-right: 18px;
    }
  }
}

#source_order {
  right: 60px;

  .data-source-panel {
    flex-direction: column;

    .data-source-info {
      margin: 5px 0;
    }
  }
}

.data-source-button {
  display: block;
  width: 220px;
  height: 68px;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  margin: 18.75rem auto 0;
  color: white;
  background-color: #FF9700;
}
```

Comment: Be clear on this, Are you looking for a pure css solution or JavaScript can be included ?

Comment: Anything really css,js,svg I'm just confused about how to go about this

Comment: You need to create a transparent canvas that fits all div. Then with some Javascript, you should able to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really a math enthusiast, i managed to find a formula on the internet to do what you wanted.

Source [Pen](https://codepen.io/J-Roel/pen/wWGNQN) Instead of following the mouse i made it so it follows the button
PS: I removed the the html on the right for the sake of this explanation.

i know it's not a complete answer, but you can adjust it from here.

```js
window.onresize = pointing;

function pointing() {

  let point = document.querySelector('.data-source-button');
  let rad = Math.atan2(point.offsetLeft, point.offsetTop);
  let left = (rad * (20 / Math.PI) * -5) + 60;


  document.querySelector('.leftArrow').style.transform = "rotate(" + left + "deg)"
}

pointing();
```

```css
.app-info-panel {
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 30rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.app-info-panel h1 {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.data-source-panel-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  user-select: none;
}

.data-source-panel-wrapper .source-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
  bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 12.5rem;
  color: #D6D7D8;
  transform-origin: left;
  z-index: 1;
}

.data-source-panel-wrapper h1 {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  color: #0481E2;
  text-align: center;
}

.data-source-panel {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.37);
  z-index: 2;
}

.data-source-panel .data-source-info h3 {
  color: #0481E2;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  font-size: .8rem;
  line-height: normal;
}

.data-source-panel .data-source-info h2 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: normal;
}

#source_report .data-source-panel .data-source-info {
  margin-right: 18px;
}

.data-source-button {
  display: block;
  width: 220px;
  height: 68px;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  margin: 18.75rem auto 0;
  color: white;
  background-color: #FF9700;
}
```

```html
<div class='app-info-panel'>
  <div class='app-info-panel-header'>
    <h1>Data-sources</h1>
  </div>

  <div class='data-source-panel-wrapper' id='source_report'>
    <h1>Report_File</h1>
    <div class='data-source-panel'>
      <div class='data-source-info'>
        <h3>Report Id</h3>
        <h2>1</h2>
      </div>
      <div class='data-source-info'>
        <h3>Report Name</h3>
        <h2>Medicine-stock</h2>
      </div>
      <div class='data-source-info'>
        <h3>Date</h3>
        <h2>02/16/18</h2>
      </div>
      <div class='data-source-info'>
        <h3>Reporter</h3>
        <h2>John Smith</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='source-arrow leftArrow' style=" top: -10px">
      &#10141;
    </div>
  </div>



  <div>
    <button class='data-source-button'>Order Filling</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Oh I actually fixed it by using a canvas overlay but this way would also work!

Comment: Right, a canvas is much more convenient to use, there's a lot of frameworks that makes drawing super easy.